# Rails how to restrict showing json format to only development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, controller

In my rails 4.1.6 application, I would like to prohibit accessing a url such as

```
www.mysite.com/models.json
```

in production but allow it in development.

How can I modify default controller actions like;

```
  # GET /models/1
  # GET /models/1.json
  def show
  end
```

to achieve this?

If the environment is production, I would like the response to be something like page not found or page inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Rails.env.production?` to restrict the URLs. I prefer doing it in `routes.rb`, but you can also use it in the action.

In `routes.rb` restrict the URL by adding the `if Rails.env.production?` to the path.

If it's in action it will look like

```
def show
  render status: 401 if Rails.env.production?
end
```

If you add the condition in routes to block the request at routes level, then the return status code will be `404`. If you want the status `inaccessible` then you need to return the `401` from controller.

Comment: But what do I wrap the if around? It's implicit and as show above my def show method contains nothing. I tried wrapping it around respond_to format.json and it did not restrict it.

Comment: In action you dont need to wrap around anything. You can add `render status: 401 if Rails.env.production?` to the action.

Comment: That would render 401 for any request in production, where would I put render?